# Data transfer over wifi

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, networking, wifi

I have create a hotspot/wifi-direct on an android device.And connect this wifi with iOS devices.
    Now i want to create a iOS App which will be able to send and receive the data over wifi.
    Is it possible if yes then how I can do this ?

Comment: yes it is possible( you can consider [Xender](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/xender-file-transfer-sharing/id898129576?mt=8) as example) but it is too lengthy to explain here. You should find some tutorials for the same!

Comment: @Lion can you put some link or answer. Thanks

Comment: one of your devices has to be a server, the other - a client. Then you can define the way, they will communicate.

Comment: As connection has been established. So now can we use socket for data transfer ?

Comment: As connection has been established.
As per my understanding iOS devices is working as client and android devices is working as a server Now in my iOS App I need to write "data receiver" for receiving data from server and a "data transmitter" for sending data to server.
So I am looking for this "Receiver and Transmitter" sample code

Comment: Can any one please provide a sample code of TCP socket-client in iOS (Objective-C) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible, you can run local server on android, I recommend https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd
then you must get ip address on iOS device to do http requests, there is c method to get route ip address

```
#include "IpHelper.h" // my header file

#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#include <net/route.h>
#else
#include "route.h"
#endif

#define CTL_NET         4               /* network, see socket.h */

#if defined(BSD) || defined(__APPLE__)

#define ROUNDUP(a) \
((a) > 0 ? (1 + (((a) - 1) | (sizeof(long) - 1))) : sizeof(long))

int getdefaultgateway(in_addr_t * addr)
{
    int mib[] = {CTL_NET, PF_ROUTE, 0, AF_INET,
        NET_RT_FLAGS, RTF_GATEWAY};
    size_t l;
    char * buf, * p;
    struct rt_msghdr * rt;
    struct sockaddr * sa;
    struct sockaddr * sa_tab[RTAX_MAX];
    int i;
    int r = -1;
    if(sysctl(mib, sizeof(mib)/sizeof(int), 0, &l, 0, 0) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if(l>0) {
        buf = malloc(l);
        if(sysctl(mib, sizeof(mib)/sizeof(int), buf, &l, 0, 0) < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        for(p=buf; p<buf+l; p+=rt->rtm_msglen) {
            rt = (struct rt_msghdr *)p;
            sa = (struct sockaddr *)(rt + 1);
            for(i=0; i<RTAX_MAX; i++) {
                if(rt->rtm_addrs & (1 << i)) {
                    sa_tab[i] = sa;
                    sa = (struct sockaddr *)((char *)sa + ROUNDUP(sa->sa_len));
                } else {
                    sa_tab[i] = NULL;
                }
            }

            if( ((rt->rtm_addrs & (RTA_DST|RTA_GATEWAY)) == (RTA_DST|RTA_GATEWAY))
               && sa_tab[RTAX_DST]->sa_family == AF_INET
               && sa_tab[RTAX_GATEWAY]->sa_family == AF_INET) {


                if(((struct sockaddr_in *)sa_tab[RTAX_DST])->sin_addr.s_addr == 0) {
                    char ifName[128];
                    if_indextoname(rt->rtm_index,ifName);

                    if(strcmp("en0",ifName)==0){

                        *addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *)(sa_tab[RTAX_GATEWAY]))->sin_addr.s_addr;
                        r = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        free(buf);
    }
    return r;
}

#endif
```

also you need to download and import route.h from apple open-sources from here https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/net/route.h

And at the end you are able to get local http url `http://+'ip you get before'+ :'port of server you lunched on android'`

so, now you are ready to do http request via ALamofire(or other) to local server.

**EDIT 1:**
I found this code in my old projects you can do data transfer with CocoaAsyncSocket, it is written in swift 3,  I know that you want some code written on objC, but can not find such , sorry if i can't fully answer your question.

```
import CocoaAsyncSocket
import UIKit

enum TAG: Int {
    case header = 1
    case body   = 2
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, NetServiceDelegate, NetServiceBrowserDelegate, GCDAsyncSocketDelegate {

    var service : NetService!
    var socket  : GCDAsyncSocket!
    var newSocket: GCDAsyncSocket!
    var serviceBrowser = NetServiceBrowser()
    var adresses: [Data]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startTalking()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func parseHeader(data: NSData) -> UInt {
        var out: UInt = 0
        data.getBytes(&out, length: MemoryLayout<UInt>.size)
        return out
    }

    func handleResponseBody(data: NSData) {
        if let message = NSString(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
            print(message)
        }
    }

    func sendText() {
        if let data = "aaaaa".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            var header = data.count
            let headerData = NSData(bytes: &header, length: MemoryLayout<UInt>.size)
            self.socket.write(headerData as Data, withTimeout: -1.0, tag: TAG.header.rawValue)
            self.socket.write(data, withTimeout: -1.0, tag: TAG.body.rawValue)
        }
    }

    func startTalking () {
        self.socket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
        self.socket.isIPv4PreferredOverIPv6 = false

        do {
            try self.socket.connect(toHost: "localhost", onPort: UInt16(8080), withTimeout: -1)
        } catch let err {
            print(err)
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Delegates of NSNetService
     **/


    func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser, didFindDomain domainString: String, moreComing: Bool) {
        print(111)
    }


    func netService(_ sender: NetService, didNotResolve errorDict: [String : NSNumber]) {
        print("aaaaaaa")
    }

    func netServiceDidPublish(_ sender: NetService) {
        print("Bonjour service published. domain: \(sender.domain), type: \(sender.type), name: \(sender.name), port: \(sender.port)")
    }

    func netService(_ sender: NetService, didNotPublish errorDict: [String : NSNumber]) {
        print("Unable to create socket. domain: \(sender.domain), type: \(sender.type), name: \(sender.name), port: \(sender.port), Error \(errorDict)")
    }

    func netService(_ sender: NetService, didAcceptConnectionWith inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream) {
        print("4")
    }

    /*
     *  END OF Delegates
     **/

    /*
     *  Delegates of GCDAsyncSokcket
     **/

    func socketDidSecure(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket) {
        print("3")
    }

    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host: String, port: UInt16) {
        print("connected")
        self.socket.readData(toLength: UInt(MemoryLayout<UInt64>.size), withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
    }

    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didAcceptNewSocket newSocket: GCDAsyncSocket) {
        print("Did accept new socket")
        self.newSocket = newSocket

        self.newSocket.readData(toLength: UInt(MemoryLayout<UInt64>.size), withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
        print("Connected to " + self.service.name)
    }

    func socketDidDisconnect(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, withError err: Error?) {
        print("Socket disconnected: error \(err)")
        if self.socket == socket {
            //            print("Disconnected from " + self.service.name)
        }
    }

    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didRead data: Data, withTag tag: Int) {
        if data.count == MemoryLayout<UInt>.size {
            let bodyLength: UInt = self.parseHeader(data: data as NSData)
            sock.readData(toLength: bodyLength, withTimeout: -1, tag: TAG.body.rawValue)
        } else {
            self.handleResponseBody(data: data as NSData)
            sock.readData(toLength: UInt(MemoryLayout<UInt>.size), withTimeout: -1, tag: TAG.header.rawValue)
        }
    }

    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didWriteDataWithTag tag: Int) {
        print("Write data with tag of \(tag)")
    }

    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didReceive trust: SecTrust, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(true)
    }

    /*
     *  END OF Delegates
     **/
}
```

**EDIT 2:** 
To parse ip to human readable string here is Objc method for it

```
+ (NSString *)getGatewayIP {
    NSString *ipString = nil;
    struct in_addr gatewayaddr;
    int r = getdefaultgateway(&(gatewayaddr.s_addr));
    if(r >= 0) {
        ipString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",inet_ntoa(gatewayaddr)];
        NSLog(@"default gateway : %@", ipString );
    } else {
        NSLog(@"getdefaultgateway() failed");
    }

    return ipString;
}
```

Comment: Can any one please provide a sample code of TCP socket-client in iOS (Objective-C) ?

Comment: I have used "IpHelper.h" for getting the IP of router but it is not giving correct IP.It's return "29825196" but IP is "172.24.199.1"

Comment: I got correct IP by using "                        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)(sa_tab[RTAX_GATEWAY]))->sin_addr)]);"

Comment: You must parse it to human readable string, sorry thats my fail , I will edit answer with that code in few minutes